# Is there any way to export the model from the OPC server?

Tags: c#, server, opc-ua, opc

I am creating an OPC server using the .net standard. I have already added functions to it that allow me to dynamically add new objects and variables, now I would like to implement a function that will export current model from the server and save it. I want to know if there is any built-in solution to my problem?
Looking through the opc example projects I have not come across any answer.

Comment: The model is a schema and normally saved as XML.  See : https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part6/v104/docs/F.1

Comment: Yes some Client can do this. I think SiOME form Siemens and the full licence from UaExpert.

Comment: I know how the model is stored, the problem is that after adding new objects to a running server they only exist as long as the server is running, I am looking for a way to create a new .xml or NodeSet2.xml file on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the model somehow stored. You load it to the server. Then you add new items to the server. At this place you need to add these items to the model too and update model's storage.